Не передается post запрос с квадратными скобками?
<form method="post" id="sendmail" name="sendmail" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="name" type="text" name="xfield[name]">
<button name="submit" id='submit' type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>

<script>
$("#sendmail").on("submit", function(){
    $.post({
        url: '/trans.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $("#sendmail").serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#butSub").val('Отправка...');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#butSub").val('Успешно');
        }
   });return false;
});  
</script>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["xfield"])){
        $name = $_POST["xfield"]["name"];
    }

Из-за квадратных скобок не могу получить данные в php? Все варианты не работают, что не так?
$name = $_POST["xfield[name]"];


Ну как минимум вы вообще не передаёте в запросе никакие данные

Почему? Если пишу без скобок, данные передаются, но мне нельзя убирать эти скобки name="xfield[name]"

@steep ну наверное потому что внутри $.post() Вы не передаете data, jQuery.post()

Вы не отправляете данные через ajax, точнее, там не хватает данных, которые надо передавать в ключе data. Самый простой способ сделать это написать так:
data: $(this).serialize(),


Эта запись есть, я не стал весь код в вопрос добавлять. Но все работает и данные отправляются. Кроме тех, что в квадратных скобках
